# Догнать практику теорией

Tags: php

Собственно хочу задать вопрос. Примерный тут вопрос уже звучал по поводу, сможет ли самоучка стать успешным программистом в том или ином направлении. Собственно стал довольно успешным прогером в php направлении. Мой минус - это теория в php. К тому же норм режу JS.

Вот собственно сам global - нужно ли идти в академию, имея достойный багаж знаний (на практике), чтобы заучить теорию?

Comment: зачем заучивать? ИМХО - просто читай книги...<br>
Теорию надо не заучивать а знать и понимать, от заучивания толка мало, а для понимания и знания достаточно желания и книг :)

Comment: А какая **теория** специфична для ПХП ?

Comment: гавно вопрос) все тут по ходу профи)))

Comment: @avp, тесты на оДеске пестрят специфичными вопросами, год назад де-то я на них жестко запоролся) Всякое там непредсказуемое поведение функций, операторов, отлов ошибок, autoload'ы и еще много всякого веселья, что-то встречается только в скриптовых языках, что-то только в пхп. Т.к. пхп у нас не учат, это можно было узнать, только читая php.net с комментариями как художку) Имхо, большинство - издержки от того, что пхп очень странный ЯП(в том смысле, что он себя давно перерос и внутри костыль на костыле).

Comment: @Sh4dow, Вот и я к тому же, что на ПХП ничего серьезного писать вообще не следует "(в том смысле, что он себя давно перерос и внутри костыль на костыле)".

Comment: @avp, ну это да. Я, чую, скоро перейду в CGI с чем-нибудь компилируемым даже в вебе. Однако php не брошу, он - шикарная заплатка =) В смысле, на нем можно делать такое: "написал - потестил - отладил - перенес на адекватный язык", ибо за данными вообще следить не надо.

Comment: Абсолютно согласен. В простых случаях (независимые запросы к страницам) ПХП хорош (а вот работоспособную **систему** на нем не сделать). А вместо CGI для серьезных вещей мне сервлеты представляются более предпочтительными.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так думаю, что образование еще никому не помешало. Особенно, если это первое ВО. Если имеете возможность, идите учиться. Уж точно это не помешает.

Answer (score 2):

Сейчас достаточно книжек по любому языку программирования. Можете изучать хоть практику, хоть теорию, короче, что вам угодно. Другое дело, что силы воли многим может и не хватать, потому что рядом нету “доброго учителя”, который в нужный момент может дать линейкой по голове за излишнее проявление лени. Самообучение иногда страдает отсутствием самодисциплины. Ну, если вы хороший программист на практике, то так ли, в самом деле, вам необходима теория? Практика в данном случае я считаю в разы важней, а необходимые теоретические знания можно дополнить, почитав соответствующую литературу.

Comment: >Другое дело, что силы воли многим может и не хватать, потому что рядом нету “доброго учителя”, который в нужный момент может дать линейкой по голове за излишнее проявление лени.

 Учителя так не делают. Это не педагогично.

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите получить первое Высшее Образование - можно пойти. Сам получил первое высшее по специальности, казалось ничего нужного они не дают (специальность достаточно общая была), но теперь понимаешь, что именно в Университете меня толково научили основам алгоритмизации + научили учиться. Ну и после сдачи сессиий никакие дедлайны тебе будут не страшны :)

Comment: Вы бы еще Физтех (или MIT) в качестве примера привели.

Answer (score 0):

Если ты хочешь устроиться работать на серьёзную работу, то могут быть проблемы, если у тебя нет высшего образования. Часто в требованиях на работе присутствует высшее образование. Самоучек не очень уважают, хотя это неправильно: ведь желания учиться у таких людей больше.
 Ещё я слышал, что в некоторых местах на собеседованиях задают очень сложные вопросы по теории, чтобы отсеять "плохих" программистов. Я считаю, что это неправильно. Они могли бы на практике сделать очень многое, больше чем студенты, которые в основном учили теорию, но мало что умеют на практике. Хотя это конечно как повезёт с институтом.

Answer (score 0):

Может конечно. Многие в России и без вышки работают лидами/IT-директорами/организаторами разработки, получая нормальную европейскую зарплату 5к евро. Только разделение теории и практики - не совсем корректно. Теория естественно никому из работодателей не нужна, зато всем нужны готовые проекты по заданию.

Если теорией в твоём понимании является знание - как написать(или организовать разработку) любой средне-большой web-проект, чтобы команда могла с ним комфортно работать, чтобы при добавлении фич(развитии) - писать не становилось всё медленнее и медленнее, чтобы проект был не бажным и не был дырявым - то да это нужно. Только в высшем учебном заведении - максимум дадут понимание что и для чего паттерны - и то не факт.

Такую "теорию" - можно выучить только работая в IT-компании, в которой > 3 программистов на протяжении минимум 3х лет - если не пинать на работе, а идти к цели развития и повышения своей стоимости на рынке кадров.

Сам отучился 2 курса и ушел работать прогером - бросив вышку. Чему непомерно рад и через 8 лет))